# FreeBSD: how to syncronize the system clock with the hardware clock in bash?

Tags: bash, freebsd, time-synchronization, timezone, clock-synchronization

I am writing a script that synchronizes the system clock with the hardware clock (aka RTC, or CMOS clock) assuming that **no** Network Time Protocol (NTP) daemon is running.

I am running in a virtual machine and the supervisor doesn't let the hardware clock to be changed by the guest.

So in linux, I can use the `hwclock --hctosys` to do this, in Debian for example:

```
$ date
Thu May 18 00:48:57 UTC 2017
$ date 0401121621
Thu Apr  1 12:16:00 UTC 2021
$ hwclock --hctosys # this set my system clock to the hardware clock back again
$ date
Thu May 18 00:49:28 UTC 2017
```

But how can I do the same thing on FreeBSD as it doesn't provide the hwclock utility? I tried using `adjkerntz -a` but it didn't work.
I am running FreeBSD version 11.0-RELEASE-p9

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

Check `sysctl machdep.disable_rtc_set`. It should be `0`, and hardware clock is set automatically every time [`settimeofday()`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=gettimeofday&sektion=2) is called. Then, if the [`ntpd`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=ntpd&sektion=8) is running, you don't have to set hardware clock with a separate command as `ntpd` already invokes this system call.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but I want to set the clock the other way around, I don't want to change the hardware clock, I want to change the system clock

Comment: Why? Your hardware clock is more reliable than NTP? Is your FreeBSD running on an atomic clock, keeping the whole Internet on correct time? :)

Comment: yes, I am running on top of an hypervisor, and I can't grant that the clients will run ntp, but the clock in the hypervisor (which I control) is reliable

Answer (score 1):

See answer 1 (below?) for general advice.

In order to make sure that ntpd will set the clock it should be run with the -g switch. Or if you do it by hand "ntpd -g -n". The last switch is to make sure that it does not fork. The first sets the time regardless. Watch the messages and exit using ^C. If it does not work, try using it with two -g switches.

Turn on ntp by enabling it in /etc/rc.conf
There should be something like the following if ntpd is enabled.
ntpd_enable="YES"
ntpd_flags="-p /var/run/ntpd.pid -f /var/db/ntpd.drift -g -g"

Start the service with the command
   service ntpd start

openntpd sets the time when it starts so it seems to not need the -g option.